# looping change function jquery with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3, bonfire

I want loop id peminjaman_id_barang many times. I use ajax in my function...
here my function. I use codeigniter 3 and bonfire framework

```
$("#peminjaman_id_barang").change(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var nilai = "<?php echo base_url('admin/inventaris/peminjaman/stok')?>";
        var peminjaman_id_barang = {peminjaman_id_barang:$("#peminjaman_id_barang").val()};
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url : nilai,
            data: {"ci_csrf_token" : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>',
                    "peminjaman_id_barang" : $("#peminjaman_id_barang").val()},
            success: function(msg){
                $('#peminjaman_id_stok').html(msg);
            }
        });

        var nilai = "<?php echo base_url('admin/inventaris/peminjaman/sewa')?>";
        var peminjaman_id_barang = {peminjaman_id_barang:$("#peminjaman_id_barang").val()};
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url : nilai,
            data: {"ci_csrf_token" : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>',
                    "peminjaman_id_barang" : $("#peminjaman_id_barang").val()},
            success: function(msg){
                $('#peminjaman_harga_sewa').html(msg);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: My eyes bleed when I see php code in javascript.

Comment: `.change(function me(e){` ... `me(e)`

Comment: @dandavis that's not work.

Comment: @Avenoir Much better than JS in PHP.